# TensorFlow error : checked narrowing failed; values not equal post-conversion Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: tensorflow, gpgpu

I'm using TensorFlow 1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 system. When I tried to set the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` to 10 to allow the GPU to use system memory to train a ResNet on very large RGB images (12000, 12000, 3), I got an error:

```
F:tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:91] Checked failed narrow == wide (-1990967296 vs 2304000000) checked narrowing failed; values not equal post-conversion Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code block referenced above is as follows:

```
// Converts (via narrowing) a type T value to a type U, and checks that the
// value has no value change due to the conversion.
template <typename WideT, typename NarrowT>
NarrowT CheckedNarrowing(const WideT& wide) {
NarrowT narrow = wide;
CHECK_EQ(narrow, wide)
    << "checked narrowing failed; values not equal post-conversion";
return narrow;
}
```

A slightly smaller image, say (10000, 10000, 3), doesn't generate this error. I'm wondering what actually caused this problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: The code is checking conversion of some dimension to what is effectively a signed  `int` quantity.  The 2304000000 number is 12000*12000*16.  This won't fit in a signed 32-bit integer quantity, which can hold a maximum of 2147483647 safely.  When you switch to `(10000,10000,3)` the equivalent product 10000*10000*16 will fit in a signed 32-bit integer type.  One way to fix this would be to use an image where the product of the dimensions is less than 2147483647/16

Comment: Any ideas outside of using a smaller image?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you try running your code again with the latest TF version and  updated CUDA. Please check [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13984#issuecomment-919629773) similar resolved issue for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error. Only way to solve it appears to be reducing data size. Recent versions of tf also did not solve the problem. TFer2 : the error in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13984#issuecomment-919629773 is not same as this one